# How To Get Json Data in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i'm trying to carry my android app to windows phone 8 enviroment.

The question is clear, how can i get my json data from web api into my application ?

It can be LongListSelector or Grid to fill.. Doesn't matter.

I were using $ajax or $getJson in android application and i asked the question here again and you cool people helped me about it.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476635/how-to-get-json-data-into-jquery-mobile-application)

I should make httprequest or something here now but couldn't find an example. Can anyone help me about with small example or clear links etc.

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of examples of using JSON data in Windows Phone 8 application.  There is a Google Drive WP8 application I remember looking at.  I would look at that, it can be found, by doing a google search for the project.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `HttpRequest`-class.

A good example can be found at the MSDN-website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Alternatively, do a google search for "HttpWebRequest async sample".

When you do that, you will receive a string. You should then create a class that mimics your JSON object. Then you can serialize the JSON into the class and bind it to your `LongListSelector`.

You could use the built-in `DataContractSerializer` for deserialisation but I prefer the serializer JSON.NET which can be found here (or via NuGet): http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer my friend. But, i'm not good at C#. Is there any step by step guide ? For example; 1-create a class, 2-begin request, 3-getresponse, 4,5,6,.... something like that.

Comment: I would go step-by-step. First of all try the tutorial in the link I passed you so that you can connect to the service and obtain the raw JSON-data as a string. Once you have done that I can help you with the next step

Comment: Okay, i will write here. Thanks

Comment: i made connection with api server and got the json data into my textblock. Now, how can put the value of data into table. for example i got, hometeamscore : 72, awayteamscore:65.. In javascript, i was using each function and gets the <td> "+value.hometeamscore+"</td> something like that. Thanks.

Comment: You should create a class that represents your JSON structure. You can check out this documentation on how to deserialize the JSON into your class: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ To do follow the tutorial you'd need to add the JSON.NET NuGet package